# Do I have to install a vent to add a bar sink in my basement?

Tags: plumbing

I want to add a small bar sink in my basement.   I have 1 1/2" line transitioning into a 2" before it goes into the floor coming from the kitchen sink above, it is 48" from the location I want put the sink.   Do I need to run a vent up or am I close enough not to add a vent

Answer (score 2):

> [Do I need a separate vent stack for my kitchen sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/do-i-need-a-separate-vent-stack-for-my-kitchen-sink?rq=1)
>
> ... in my state (VA), the allowable distance between a 1 1/2" drain trap (standard size for a kitchen sink) and its vent is 6 feet. If your trap is farther from the vent than that, then you should consider adding a new vent or an [air admittance valve](https://www.google.com/#q=air+admittance+valve).

If your local codes allow them, the 2" pipe may serve as a *wet vent*. According to the [IPC](http://publicecodes.cyberregs.com/icod/ipc/2003/icod_ipc_2003_9_sec009.htm) an `X` size stack can handle `Y` number of DFU.

`1.5" : 1 DFU`
`2"   : 4 DFU`
`2.5" : 6 DFU`
`3"   : 12 DFU`

*DFU* or Drain Fixture Units, where the [UPC](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drainage-fixture-unit-values-d_1077.html) allows for bar sinks to count as `1` and kitchen sinks to count as `2`.

So long as these are the only two fixtures discharging into the 2" pipe, you're within nominal code not to add a vent but you still need to check your local codes.

Comment: +1 to "check your local codes"... air admittance valves are handy, but seem to be very hit/miss in various jurisdictions.